# prototypes and replacing missing variables in Random Forests algorithm

Tags: self-study, classification, random-forest

I'm new with Random forests Classification algorithm, and I have some questions about concepts confused me,

1. What is the role of prototypes in the classification operation, Are they the core of the classification process, Are they represent the **model** of the classification.
2. I have read that Random forests support the replacing of missing variables, Is that mean, If I have a 15 variable then I could pass 13 variable, and the model, which is build by Random forests will find an approximation for the missing two variables?

Answer (score 0):

(1) The prototypes function is used for when RF are used for clustering (unsupervised learning) rather than classification.
(2) Not all implementations support missing values. RF can support missing values - not variables.